# Launch url to start a script like a cronjob?

Tags: scripts, cron

I have a website on mutualised hosting (server A).
I need to run every minutes a script, I just need to go to http//www.mysiteserverA.com/run.php
I searsch a solution automaticly run this script every minutes.

I know there are some cron job specialised website but I searsch a free solution, then...

I have an Ubuntu Desktop LTS server. (Server B)
I try with the application "Sheduled Task" but apparently I can use only commands and no url...

Someone have an idea how I can launch this url every minutes from my Server B ?

Thanks a lot.

Oliver.

Comment: Did you try `wget http//www.mysiteserverA.com/run.php` as a command in the scheduled tasks?

Answer (score 2):

Since the scheduled tasks needs a command, and apparently simply visiting the URL is all that's needed, you can use a program which will fetch that URL:

```
wget http//www.mysiteserverA.com/run.php
```

This actually downloads the response from that page (to somewhere, I'm not sure where the scheduler sets the working directory to). To suppress this, and any other output, you might try:

```
wget -q -o /dev/null http//www.mysiteserverA.com/run.php
```

Or

```
curl -s http//www.mysiteserverA.com/run.php > /dev/null
```

Comment: exactly, with my first try he download only the response but now with your tip that work perfectly ! Thanks a lot !